# Strange behaviour in rails; a rewritten bit of active record / view code is unexpectedly taking longer to run not less time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, activerecord, view

This is a bit of a strange one.

In rails I have page that sometimes took a while to load (around 12 seconds). So I attempted to re-write it so large sections used cached queries instead of find's on their associations, I'll explain below:

Sample code before I tried to speed it up:

Let's say each user belongs to an account, so before it looked like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The view:

```
@users = User.all

<% @users.each do | user | %>
    <%= user.account.name %>
<% end %>
```

This in the log would cause individual queries for each user/account association. So there would be 100's of queries that look something like this:

```
select * from accounts where account.id = 1;
```

So when each user's account was looked up, an individual query looked up the account via a find from the user's account_id.

I attempted to speed this page up by looking up all the accounts in one query, via and IN() to start with and then detecting them when they are needed like so:

In the rails app there was this code now:

```
@users = User.all
@all_accounts = Account.where(:id => users.map{ | user | user.account_id } )

<% @users.each do | user | %>
    <%= @all_accounts.detect{ | a | a.id == user.account_id }.name %>
<% end %>
```

This means each line a cache query is called that take's 0 seconds to run instead of 100's of individual selects.

**This is where it all gets very strange…**

In the first example the active record part of the page rendering takes around 6000ms and the view part takes around 6000ms. So about 12 seconds in all, which is rubbish.

I was expecting the re-written code with the detect in it to be musch quicker however the active record part on the page rendering too 1000ms (a second) and the view part took around 30 seconds!

What on earth is going on here? How come the view is taking around half a minute to render?

Let's assume that is page cannot be paginated, as per a client request. And it cannot have an infinite scroll either, the whole page needs to be rendered quicker. Obviously I could also use memcaching built into rails, but let's assume this isn't an option either. And also it would still need to load fast the first time it's rendered before it's memcached.

So why's it taking so long in the view? Any in sights would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why not set an :include in your users query ? It works like your little patch on @all_accounts...
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use rails default mechanism to include associations in the query.
Furthermore you should use find_each while iterating over a large dataset. It fetches objects in batches and thus safes memory:

```
@users = User.includes(:account)

<% @users.find_each do | user | %>
  <%= user.account.name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's taking an age because `@all_accounts = Account.where(:id => users.map{ | user | user.account_id } )` doesn't actually run that query. The query runs when it's actually needed, i.e. when you call `detect`.

It's running the `Account` query for every user, and this is obviously a heftier query than your original ones as it's pulling tons of `Account`s each time, hence the long wait.

Solution is obviously to do what the others have recommended and use `includes`, but sticking `.all` on the end of your `Account`s query might work too by making that query execute in the first instance.